# Working with System.Drawing in .net to create a Captcha

Tags: c#, .net, image, drawing, captcha

I have generated 6 digits alphanumeric text in c# and now I need to display it as image. For this I use  `Bitmap` and `Graphics` in .Net .

As a result of this I am able to get the image but I need some small changes in the fonts of the image like we see in Captcha Challenge zigzag kind of thing to make it a bit difficult to read.

Here is my code...

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 30);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.Navy);
string randomString = CaptchaImageResult.GetCaptchaString(6);
g.DrawString(randomString, new Font("Courier", 16), 
             new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke), 2, 2);
HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
bmp.Save(response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmp.Dispose();
new CaptchaChallenge { Captcha = bmp };
```

Update..

I tried with this code but the letters are not clear..

```
 Brush zigzagBrush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchBrush(
                         System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchStyle.ZigZag, Color.White);
 g.DrawString(randomString, new Font("Courier", 16), zigzagBrush, 2, 2);
```

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is. So you get the image but it is to clear to read, yes? Then you should 1) write letter by letter 2) change fonts/sizes  and include some translation and rotation 3) add some lines etc. - Distorting the drawing is a little hard with GDI+, though..

Comment: @TaW Thanks for your response..I will try to make it more clear ..We know Captcha Challenge !!..The letters there are hard to read , Same way i need to display the image by the above code that i posted .

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169371/Captcha-Image-using-C-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @TaW I updated my post ..Please have alook

Comment: Try making the brush more transparent

Comment: Using a HatchBrush is a good idea! Try to write the same 2-3 times with varying colors & hatch patterns, maybe with a semi-tranparent brush and a tiny offset in the location. Captchas are always a trial and error game finding the right balance..

Comment: @FarhanAnam That link you posted is fine.  Throw it in an answer with some explanation on how it works and it'd be a good answer.

Comment: There are multiple ways to distort an image - I doubt you'll get a decent result (hard for machines, easy for humans) just by adding a `HatchStyle` on a font.

Comment: Thank you all of you..I am able to solve the problem.Now its displaying fine..Thanks ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hatch brush overlay would be better :

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 30);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.Navy);
g.DrawString(code, new Font("Courier", 16),
                     new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke), 2, 2);
g.FillRectangle(new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,0),Color.Transparent), g.ClipBounds );
g.FillRectangle(new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.ForwardDiagonal, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), Color.Transparent), g.ClipBounds);
```

Comment: Good, I stil need to be able to draw zig-zag text